# User unique identity in microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the next endpoint for getting
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=id, displayName, mail, userPrincipalName"
According to docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0
there is no any info about unique mail property for **user resource type**.

`mail     String  The SMTP address for the user, for example, "jeff@contoso.onmicrosoft.com". Supports $filter.`

Question: is it possible to get two or more users (with different ids) and the same mail property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User mail property should be unique.

You will get the following error message when you try to create a new user with the same mail property.

```
"error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Another object with the same value for property proxyAddresses already exists.",
```

Comment: thanks for response. One more question. How did you make request? You made POST request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users and received described above answer?

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users`
`{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "displayName-value",
    "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
    "userPrincipalName": "upntest@xxx.live",
    "mail": "srxxx@xx.com",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
        "password": "XXXX@234"
    }
}`